# Corda-template build error

Tags: corda

I have been using corda template 12.1 version so far and now i want to migrate to version 1. I have downloaded corda template v1.0 and tried build but it failed with the error as below.

Error:(97, 0) Could not find net.corda:corda-core:0.14-SNAPSHOT.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/corda/corda-core/0.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/corda/corda-core/0.14-SNAPSHOT/corda-core-0.14-SNAPSHOT.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/corda/corda-core/0.14-SNAPSHOT/corda-core-0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar
    file:/C:/Users/463193/.m2/repository/net/corda/corda-core/0.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
    file:/C:/Users/463193/.m2/repository/net/corda/corda-core/0.14-SNAPSHOT/corda-core-0.14-SNAPSHOT.pom
    file:/C:/Users/463193/.m2/repository/net/corda/corda-core/0.14-SNAPSHOT/corda-core-0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/corda-core/0.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/corda-core/0.14-SNAPSHOT/corda-core-0.14-SNAPSHOT.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/corda-core/0.14-SNAPSHOT/corda-core-0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar
    https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed/net/corda/corda-core/0.14-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

Required by:
    project :java-source
Open File

I tried installing the Corda main repo v1.0 even that throws an error saying "Repository not found". How do i migrate to v1.0 of corda?

Answer (score 0):

The old CorDapp template, which included both Java and Kotlin source-code, was deprecated, and never updated to Corda v1.0.

Instead, we created two separate templates for v1.0:

- One for Java only: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java
- One for Kotlin only: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin